# Heroku & Rails - Varnish HTTP Cache Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, varnish, http-caching

My heroku website's root page is essentially static, it has some ruby code in the view when its generated, but there's nothing specific to a single user, so I'd like to have it cached by Varnish and served up without hitting my dyno (note that there are other pages that are dynamic in the application).

Heroku makes it seem very simple [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching). Just add  `response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=300'` and it'll cache for 5 minutes before regenerating.

To test this I made the changed and outputted the date (`Time.now`) to the page, to see if it would remain the same for 5 minutes, but every time I access the page on a new browser it updates. Refreshing on the same browser works fine, but I think that's because of the browser caching, not Heroku.

If it's any help, when I do a curl -i to get the HTTP headers, I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Server: nginx/0.7.67^M
Date: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 02:03:33 GMT^M
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300^M
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge^M
Etag: "8a1b58f048968803980417a2914764d0"^M
X-Runtime: 0.038393^M
Content-Length: 8310^M
X-Varnish: 1040651825^M
Age: 0^M
Via: 1.1 varnish^M
```

Basically, I'd like to make sure that it's generated once and then cached in Varnish, am I missing any options, do I have to configure something more? If you have other suggestions for serving a fast static page I'd love those as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Also note that I do have an authentication system which may add some before_filters, but they don't have an effect on the output of the main page.

Comment: Can I just confirm you're running on the Aspen or Bamboo stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that Heroku has a number of Varnish servers, so it takes about 10-15 page refreshes until the page was cached on all of the servers, after that it would stay cached. It was working all along, I just gave up after a few refreshes didn't work.

I also increased the max_age so that I could see it more clearly, a 5 minute cache has almost no effect.

Answer (score 3):

I beleive that there is something in your application causing this issue (possibly the headers aren't being set correctly?).

To test this I put up an application that contains one cached, and one un-cached page (nothing other than rendering the text to the output.

http://morning-earth-1972.heroku.com/base/cache

http://morning-earth-1972.heroku.com/base/no_cache

Notice that the cache version will not change within five minutes of the time printed.

The source can be found here:  https://github.com/neilmiddleton/heroku_varnish_test_SO_8663326

Therefore, Heroku is working as you would expect.  I would initially look at your auth system to check that that isn't doing something, as this is quite a common scenario (to ensure that cached pages are fully secured)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My auth system does have a before_filter, will that prevent caching?

Comment: Interesting, I think my problem may be due to the fact that Heroku has multiple Varnish servers so you need to have many hits to cache it in each one. I was refreshing a few times and then giving up because nothing was cached, you really have to refresh around 10-15 times but after that it works. Interestingly though, your implementation doesn't seem to suffer from that, perhaps due to something Heroku does in the backend.

Comment: Not sure you're right.  Yes Heroku has many varnish servers but they function as a single cluster and a single cache.

Comment: Hmm... well after I refresh a few times, I get a bunch of different dates, but they're all old dates. I've made sure I'm on Incognito mode so that I have no cookies or such. I notice that your app doesn't suffer from that though =S...

Comment: How many dynos are you running?  Are you sure you're not caching to the disk on the local dyno (you can write to /tmp)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are sending cookies when testing with your browser ? What are your request headers ?

What do you get if your run curl -I http://host.com/ twice ?

Comment: Does it matter if I'm sending cookies when I'm testing with my browser? Shouldn't Varnish cache regardless of the presence of cookies?

Comment: Running curl -l twice gives me the same result, the date is generated each time.

Comment: I do not know how Heroku's Varnish is configured, if you know how, or have access to the VCL file it would be useful to post it here. However in the default VCL file Varnish is configured to pass the request to the backend server in presence of Cookies. The rationale is the following : if you have a cookie, it is because you are authenticated on you website and you most likely do not want to get a cached page so you can see your personnalized informations, if any.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Heroku is configured to cache regardless of cookies.