# Heroku & Rails - Varnish is only caching very occasionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, varnish, http-caching

I have an issue similar to [Heroku & Rails - Varnish HTTP Cache Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663326/heroku-rails-varnish-http-cache-not-working), but the solution (wait for a while, then everything works) doesn't seem to apply - I've had the setup below for several days.

[This thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.rails.heroku/8229) on the Heroku Google group has some users with the same problem. They mention that it takes a while for everything to be cached, but my understanding is that after a while, everything should get cached, no? Or does that only apply if there is a Lot of traffic?

I need some advice on where I should be looking/what I can try changing in order to get caching working properly.

### My setup:

I have http://www.swingoutlondon.co.uk running on Heroku (Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.9.2, bamboo-mri-1.9.2) and the main index page performs a lot of database queries to return what is essentially a static page - usually taking about 2-3 seconds *(yes, that's something I really do need to address, but I figure varnish caching is a quick win)*.

I've set the `Cache-Control` response header as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching), and indeed that does seem to have been set on the page:

```sh
>> curl -I http://swingoutlondon.co.uk

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 13 May 2012 00:01:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
Etag: "2565201f3ae39c6a9a1f6b1fb8bbbe0a"
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Runtime: 1.699667
Content-Length: 44224
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 681634826
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
```

Note: `Cache-Control: public, max-age=300`

I assume that `Age: 0` indicates that it hasn't retrieved a cached copy, and indeed the command returns in the normal slow 2-3 seconds.

If keep repeatedly trying that curl, I can occasionally a cached copy (the page loads in under half a second and `Age` is greater than 0).

I must confess to not fully understanding HTTP headers, but one clue might be: when `Age` is greater than 0, I get two lots of digits in `X-Varnish` (in all other cases I only get one set):

```sh
X-Varnish: 848670407 848650521
```

Here's what I've checked:

- the source of is identical each time.
- I have one `before_filter` on that page, which sets the time the page was last updated as an instance variable.
- there are a number of cookies - as far as I can see they are all set by either Google Analytics or the Twitter or Facebook buttons.

For good measure, here are my Request headers:

```sh
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=264326157.189257391.1336869624.1336869624.1336869624.1; __utmb=264326157.2.10.1336869624; __utmc=264326157; __utmz=264326157.1336869624.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:www.swingoutlondon.co.uk
If-None-Match:"2565201f3ae39c6a9a1f6b1fb8bbbe0a"
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19
```

Comment: can you confirm which stack you are running on?

Comment: @JohnBeynon - As I said in the question (4th paragraph) it's bamboo-mri-1.9.2 - That's the stack right? That's what I get when I run `heroku stack` from the command line.

Comment: Is the Etag being set by your code or Varnish?

Comment: @GarryShutler I assumed it was set by Rails under the hood. I get an etag on Localhost (i.e. without Varnish), but I'm not explicitly setting it in my code. The etag seems to be the same regardless of whether the page got cached or not.

Answer (score 2):

Ah well - turns out that because Heroku uses multiple independent Varnish servers, and because traffic to Swing Out London is relatively low, I shouldn't expect to have many pages served by the caches if my max-age is only 5 minutes. Setting it to 20 or 30 minutes results in much more caching.

I've written a detailed [blog post](http://duncangmstuart.co.uk/blog/2012/05/14/caching-with-varnish-on-heroku-rails/) collecting my learnings. Thanks to [Garry Shulter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6369/garry-shutler) for helping me out with this one.